# Set of complex convergent sequences is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A=\{\alpha=(a_1,a_2,...):a_n\in\mathbb{C},\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n\text{ exists }\}$ the set of convergent complex sequences and $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ the sup norm.

> How do I prove that $(A,||\cdot||_{\infty})$ is a Banach space?

I know that I have to show that all Cauchy sequences of converging complex sequences converge, but how would I do this?

Comment: It is a closed subspace of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$. It is a standard proof that this is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $(b_n)_{n\in N}$ be a Cauchy sequence of $(A,\|\|_{\infty})$. Write $b_n=(a^m_n)_{m\in N}$   be a Cauchy sequence, show that for every $m$, the sequence $(a^m_n)_{n\in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since complex numbers are complete, the limit $b^m=lim_na^m_n$ exists. Show that $(b_n)_{n\in N}$ converges towards $b=(b^m)_{m\in N}$.

Comment: Why is $(a_n^m)_{n\in N}$ Cauchy?

Comment: Write the fact that $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence,..

Comment: So $(b_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of converging complex sequences $a^m$ right?

Comment: $\|b_n-b_{n'}\|=sup_m|a_n^m-a_{n'}^m|$. So $\|b_n-b_{n'}\|<\epsilon$ implies that $|a_n^m-a_{n'}^m|<\epsilon$ for every $m$, this is equivalent to saying that $({a^m_n})_{n\in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Im a bit confused by the sub- and superscripts. What is the difference between $(a_n^m)_{n\in N}$ and $(a_n^m)_{m\in N}$?

Comment: In the first $m$ is fixed and in the second $n$ is fixed.